# Disable the collection of linked object

Tags: collections, layers

I created a 3d house using 2.83.7. The main component are : wall , ceiling , floor , door , window etc. So i created some collection to manage it : **WALL, DOOR,FLOOR ,WINDOW** etc

**WALL** collection contains all wall object, **DOOR** collection store all doors and so on. This way i can easily isolate them when i want for example disabling just the floor and ceiling.

Now the challenge is , i want to make a master bedroom with 3 alternative. Each of this alternative will have its own wall/door/window etc. Practically there will be 3 sets of wall/door/window etc on the same spot but with different design. So later, only 1 of them can be enabled, otherwise they will overlap each other.

Then i created 3 collections :
**ROOM_ALT1, ROOM_ALT2, ROOM_ALT3**. They will be used to store associate room alternative. Only one of them will be enabled at a time.

I link the objects this collection. So for example for the room alt1 : the wall.01 , while it's  still in **WALL** collection , it will be linked to **ROOM_ALT1** .

I choose to 'link' , not to 'move' because my plan was that i want for example the wall.01 to be under both **WALL** and **ROOM_ALT1** collection. I thought i can disable any wall objects (including walls from any room alternatives) by disabling the **WALL** collection while i can also disable alt1 by disabling ROOM_ALT1. But it's not working as i expected.

Note: i want to disable/enable , not just hide/unhide them.

Any solution ? Does anyone can help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Click</kbd> on the button:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot , it works perfectly.  I was thinking to on/off that checkbox on left side of the collection name ( exclude from view layer) - not by disabling from viewport. Btw just curious, is possible to use that 'exclude from view layer' checkbox to control it ? i prefer to use it if possible because i will sent it to unity. If it's excluded from view layer in Blender, it will be gone in unity. Anyway , your solution still can work, in unity , it will be hidden rather than permanently gone. Just curious.

Comment: I don't think this is possible for view layers this way.

Comment: Ok no problem, this solved my problem . Thanks a lot.